# Why does the API return a 404 instead of a 400 if a route parameter validation fails when using route constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API project and want to validate route parameters before running business logic. Given this sample endpoint

```
[HttpGet("{username:maxlength(30)}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetUser([FromRoute] string username)
{
    // ...
}
```

the username will never be greater than 30 characters. When calling the endpoint with a username longer than 30 characters the API will respond with a 404 response. I would expect a 400 with a message like

> 'username' must be greater than 0 and smaller than 31 characters

Am I wrong? Are there any reasons for this?

Comment: Error 404 say the URL address is bad while 400 indicates a parameter in the request is bad.  A query URL sometimes will have a question mark indicating parameters.  So the 400 error will indicate the error is after the question mark.

Comment: Try using data annotations

Comment: @jbooker you mean like so? `[FromRoute][Range(1, 30)] string username`

Comment: I think for route params this should be fine `[MaxLength(30)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route constraints are used to disambiguate similar routes, if constraints are used for input validation, invalid input results in a 404 Not Found response.

For more information, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference

To produce a 400 Bad Request for invalid input(s), as mentioned in comments, some built-in attribute, such as `StringLength` etc can help achieve the requirement.